# How to translate sentences using vuei18n?

Tags: vuejs2, internationalization, vue-i18n

Currently I have been able to translate only words, but in the case of wanting to translate an entire sentence, I don't know how to do it.

taking the following example json

```
{
    "Hello":"Hola"
    "how":"como"
    "You go":"te va"
    "text 4": "texto 4"
    "text 5: "texto 5"
}
```

So when entering all the text "Hola como te va texto 4 texto 5", I must get "Hello how do you go text 4 text 5" as translation,but I only manage to do it by words, example:

```
 <p>{{$t("Hola")}}</p>
```

get in response in the browser 'Hola', indeed

Answer (score 1):

Lucky you, I just learned this about a few weeks ago.

So what you need is actually exist in the documentation. I believe it is called [Linked Local Message](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/messages.html#linked-locale-messages).

So here's an example for you..

```
{
    "Hello":"Hola",
    "how":"comp",
    "You_go":"te va",
    "text4": "texto 4",
    "text5: "texto 5",
    "sentence": "@:Hello @:how @:You_go @:text4 @:text5"
}
```

Then try

```
$t('sentence')
```

So it will actually linked to the "Hello" part of your json. So if you only have `@:Hello` at `sentence` it will result in `Hola`. It's kind of hard to read, but it's the syntax.

And if you didn't understood, I just made a fiddle for your experiment related to the feature. It has two languages that is `en` and `test` that represent whatever language you use in the example. Here is the link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/irfandyjip89/mr58xu0L/7/)

Hope it helps, feel free to ask as well :D

Comment: but in the case of just write "Hola" or "como" or "te va" or "Texto 4" or "Texto 5" I only require those translations and not the whole sentence. That is to say, in a moment there may be some and in others there may be all, that example that you gave me very interested and very grateful in advance for the estimated time, but this new doubt arose.

Comment: @JG_GJ If you just need the word then use `$t('Hello') // Will output 'Hola'`  then. Don't use the whole `$t('sentence')`. I don't know if I misunderstood what you said. But if your question need to be updated then update it, else it might be best to make another StackOverflow question. And feel free to invite me there.

Comment: What happens is that in $ t (variable_with_text) there will be a variable that will contain the string that the user enters in an input, therefore I must translate what the user enters, either a word or an entire sentence and the translation It must be according to what you have in the json.

Comment: @JG_GJ Ah I see, I don't think that `i18n` can solve your problem. What you need is some sort of AI technology. Or if you really want to work it out (which isn't a good practice), you can map out **each word** then match it with your `i18n` files. But really the problem here is how you can map out each word that you wanted to translate. The second is to match it with each one of them.

Comment: Also AFAIK, `i18n` was meant for texts that you write manually. But let's hope someone more experienced can answer your question.